java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream when reading response headers in OkHttp
I'm using OkHttp to make HTTP requests in my Java application. I'm encountering an issue where I get a java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream error when trying to read the response headers from the server. Here's the relevant code:
Response networkResponse = transport.readResponseHeaders()
        .request(networkRequest)
        .handshake(connection.getHandshake())
        .header(OkHeaders.SENT_MILLIS, Long.toString(sentRequestMillis))
        .header(OkHeaders.RECEIVED_MILLIS, Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()))
        .build();`

I've tried several things to debug and fix this issue:

Checked the server: I verified that the server is running and able to handle requests. I expected to find some server-side errors that could explain the issue, but the server logs didn't show any errors.

Checked the network: I tested my network connection to make sure it's stable. I expected that a flaky network connection might be causing the issue, but my network seems to be working fine.

Checked the request: I reviewed the request I'm sending to make sure it's valid. I expected to find a problem with the request that could be causing the server to close the connection, but the request seems to be correct.


Despite these checks, I'm still getting the java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream error. I expected the transport.readResponseHeaders() method to read the response headers from the server without any issues, but it's throwing this error instead.

Issue was with simulator file, updating the simulator data with the required response class solved the issue.
